# The fuel shut-off valve was left in over night. Is it dangerous for the plane?

Tags: fuel-systems

I forgot to pull the shut-off valve in my plane ([PZL-110 Koliber 150](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCATA_Rallye_family#Polish_production)) while I was trying to start an engine.  Will this have any effect on the plane?

It has a mixture supply knob and is a pull/push type. I have pushed in and, according to the checklists, it should stay on the pull position while the engine is not running. It is also a low-wing aeroplane.

Comment: What kind of airplane?

Comment: PZL Koliber 150. Like C172N with carburetor.

Comment: You need to explain more.  Was in OFF or out OFF?  Is it a push pull knob?  What does the POH say to do?  I have a low wing airplane with a carbureted Lycoming, and I never turn the fuel off unless I'm working on the fuel system. That is, the fuel is ON 24/7.

Comment: Sorry, i mean a mixture supply knob, it is pull/push knob. I have pushed in and according to the chcecklists it should stayed on pull position while engine is not running. It is also low wing aeroplane.

Comment: Please update the question with the details from your comments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A mixture control left at full rich has no effect on a carbureted engine when it's not running. It's just a best practice to cater to, say, some situation where someone moves the prop by hand (and they don't bother to check the controls) and it could potentially put a fuel charge in a cylinder (if they flip the prop fast enough), and maybe somehow it could fire and kick the engine over (that generally doesn't happen on a cold engine - but maybe there is a hot mag that went undetected; lots of what-ifs).

Anyway, it's a procedural fault, but no big deal.

Comment: I think you forgot the most important part - Take your wet noodle lashings and never do it again! Or else! ;)